# How many CS:EIP registers are there on a multi core processor?

Tags: cpu

I am using VS2008 to debug a GPF (ACCESS VIOLATION). Iset EIP to the crash address and it duly pops up some of my source code. It doesn't appear to be the cause of the GPF.

I am on an 8-core machine. Are there multiple CS:EIP registers on such things? If so, how do I access them in Visual Studio?

Many thanks!

Comment: each core has to have its own cs:eip, as each core can/will be at different execution points, even if they all happen to be running the same code. e.g. core 1 is 500 instructions behind the other 7 because it had to handle an OS interrupt.

Comment: My CPU information is:System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model OptiPlex 790
System Type x64-based PC
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: So how do I access each cs:eip in Visual Studio 2008's debugger?

Answer (score 1):

General Protection Fault (GPF) can be caused by any kind of invalid memory access. Not only by attempt to execute instruction on invalid memory address, but also by attempt to access operand on invalid memory address used by instruction. For example,

```
mov [eax], ebx
```

will cause GPF if value stored in eax is NULL (classical null pointer dereferencing). If Visual Studio debugger point you to some partiicalar instruction address (CS:EIP) and you can found code on that address, the reason of the fault will be address of the memory operand used by that instruction. Visual Studio by default will provide you information in the context of the faulting thread. So, there is no any reason to look into another thread contexts.

For example:
[image]

If we then open Debug->Windows->Disassembly we will see the next picture:
[image]

As you can see, GPF was rised by invalid address stored in eax. Faulted instruction address 0x012b1002 indicated in the message box on the first picture is the same that pointed by debugger on the second one. Faulted address 0x00000000 from the first picture is an address stored in eax and used as memory located parameter in the mov instruction.

Answer (score 0):

These days every core has two full sets of registers, including CS:EIP, even though in the 64 bit age CS doesn't matter much. Two because of hyper-threading (two virtual cores in one physical one, more or less). But each set of registers is independent, you won't get interference from a different process (unless your OS is really bad).

As for your problem. GPF is tricky, it may not SEEM like the problem is where the debugger says, but it's usually good to take its word for it. You may have a memory issue in your program, bad pointer, overflow, dangling pointers, uninitialized variables or some such thing. If you used Linux I'd say try valgrind. And all of that is even worse if you your application is multi-threaded.

There isn't enough information in your question, but I'd suggest rolling up your sleeves and debugging. E.g. add a bunch of assertions or logging of variables.